# Trying to do a counter object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to do a counter object in JavaScript like so:
EDIT: I've added an example

```
    let profile={skill:['javascript','javascript','html','css','css']}
    let objectCount={}

profiles.map(profile => {
        profile.skills.map(skill => {
          skill = skill.toLowerCase();
          if (!(skill in objectCount)) {
            objectCount = { ...objectCount, [skill]: 1 };
          } else {
            objectCount.skill = objectCount.skill + 1;
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

I have array of profiles and inside them an array of skills which is : 'javascript','html','css',etc 
and I wish to make an objectCount that will be:

```
objectCount={
  'html':1,
  'javascript:2,
   'css':2
}
```

but for some reason the line 
`objectCount.skill=objectCount.skill+1` doesnt work, because I get an object with 1 in every single key,
does anybody know whats my error?

Comment: It’s helpful if you post **all** the code necessary to reproduce your error. You should make this a runnable snippet.

Comment: this is the entire code , you want me to write you a sample profile with an array of skills?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to increment the value of a key `skill` on the `objectCount` object that does not exist. Instead you want to increment the value of the key that has the name of the `skill` variable. So you have to use `objectCount[skill]` instead of `objectCount.skill`:

```js
let profiles = [
  {
    skills: ['html', 'js']
  },
  {
    skills: ['html', 'php']
  }
]
let objectCount = {}

profiles.map(profile => {
  profile.skills.map(skill => {
    skill = skill.toLowerCase();
    if (!(skill in objectCount)) {
      objectCount = { ...objectCount, [skill]: 1 };
    } else {
      objectCount[skill] = objectCount[skill] + 1;
    }
  });
});
console.log(objectCount);
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the answer, but could you explain to me why the skill does not exist? I tried to run this at the javascript console:                                             object={'alex':3}
Object { alex: 3 }

object.alex=object.alex+1
4
object.alex
4

Comment: Because you define the object as `objectCount={}`, so there's no key in the object named `skill`.

Comment: yes but the if checks if the key doesnt exist, and if it does it goes to the else, which is why the skill should be in the object already, that's what confuses me.

Comment: again: If the variable `skill` is "html" for example, the line `objectCount.skill` does NOT get the `html` key of the object, but instead it tries to get a key of the name `skill`, and a key of the name `skill` is not defined on that object.anywhere in your code.

Comment: oh I see it just added the string skill instead of its value right? thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Yes, if you want to acces an object key by variable, you can do it with the array-like square bracket notation as in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of creating this counter map is to use the reduce function instead of map.

For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object